# Telekinesis on a primitive planet

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship, telekinesis

This was a book I read a few years ago as an eighth grader. I remember the book being fairly old, maybe written in the 80's?

It was a book about humans who were very advanced and went undercover to help another planet thrive. The humans taught a girl on the primitive planet telekinesis and gave them challenges to survive through.
The opening scene was the spaceship leaving I think? It had imperial in the title I believe. I don't know why I remember this but there was a scene where the humans give the girl a lantern and she asks them how they put the sun in a glass jar.

Comment: Sounds a little like Ursula Le Guin's [*Rocannanon's World*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocannon%27s_World) , except for the telekinesis.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I think I remember it having the name imperial in it possibly? I will add that. thank you though

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137223/story-with-multiple-third-planet-races (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

I think this is [Enchantress from the Stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchantress_from_the_Stars) by Sylvia Louise Engdahl. First published in 1970.

> *"Elana belongs to a peaceful, technologically advanced, space-faring civilization called the "**Federation**", which monitors worlds which
>   are still "maturing", allowing them to grow without any sort of
>   contact or intervention. Elana stows away on a ship in order to
>   accompany her father on a mission to a planet where intervention has
>   been deemed necessary because a technologically advanced empire has
>   invaded the planet in order to take advantage of its resources. In
>   order to lead a young woodcutter (a native of that planet) against
>   them (without exposing him to the truth about either alien
>   civilization) Elana takes on the role of an enchantress. She gives him
>   various tools, leading him to believe that they are magical."
>   -Wikipedia summary*

and

> *"Elana poses as an enchantress and teaches Georyn and Terwyn, two woodcutter's sons, to use **telepathy** to scare the Imperials. Before
>   this, Georyn and Terwyn are trusted with three tasks by the
>   Starwatcher, an old man who is actually Elana's father. First, they
>   must retrieve a magical disc (actually an inter-comm unit), a **piece
>   of the sun** (an electric lamp), and a magic cup (an ordinary cup
>   which Elana moves with **psychokinesis**) with Evrek, Elana's fiance,
>   as the "demon" who challenges them to reach their full potential." -
>   [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/EnchantressFromTheStars)*