# Some aliens help a struggling planet

Tags: story-identification, aliens, telekinesis

I read a book a few years ago from the 1980s, probably about a group of people from a planet going onto another planet undercover to help save them. The planet they went to was based in something resembling medieval times. A few trainers — one was named something along the lines of Gerard — trained a few people on the planet in telekinesis. The opening scene was actually an epilogue. I remember the trainers assigning challenges to these people; one was to go into some dark forest overnight. It was pretty good and I am interested in reading it again. At the end, the trainees had to fight some giant machines of another planet that wanted to take over. The cover was dark blue and I have no clue who wrote it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Telekinesis on a primitive planet](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80971/telekinesis-on-a-primitive-planet)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137223/story-with-multiple-third-planet-races (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

Enchantress From The Stars by Sylvia Engdahl. This has been [asked on here before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80971/telekinesis-on-a-primitive-planet).

Comment: To post a link; you do the following: <br>
[ write a word inside these brackets, which will be used as hyperlink]( insert the link in these brackets ). Without spaces on either ends.